# Download program for ΔG for TM insertion

Tags: proteins, sequence-analysis

I am trying to calculate the ΔG of TM insertion for many protein sequences.

Has anyone come across the source code or a programmatic version for the von Heijne ΔG for TM insertion? The web server is at http://dgpred.cbr.su.se/index.php?p=instructions

I can't find a link in the papers or on the site.

Comment: Ask the authors otherwise you'll require a "digger", (web spider). I'll share my "digger" code for another delta G website but I have not used this specific site. I think it is common for web servers not to distribute the "backend" for delta G calculations. If you get the standalone please post back. I'm about to start a very similar project (not on TM, but stability of a single antigen) and coding to explore the delta G parameter space is of a lot of interest

Comment: @MichaelG. Contacting the authors is the next step. I just want to check that I'm not missing their repo. A digger/scraper isn't ideal, unfortunately. The tool I'm building needs to be a bit of futureproof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is stored in [github](https://github.com/ElofssonLab/dgpred) (ElofssonLab/dgpred) with a link to the website.

To find it I searched for: dgpred download github